# Debounce an ng-change event in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, debouncing

What's a good way to debounce an ng-change event in angular? I know about the debounce available in ng-model options, but I want my model to update right away as its changed because the user has the option to submit this data, and I don't want any information to be missing from the post because the model was waiting for the debounce. I do want to add a debouncer on my ng-change event or the function it calls. The html for my element

```
<div ng-change="saveProg()" text-angular ng-model="message" required></div>
```

I'd like to debounce the saveProg function so it doesn't run once for every character typed, but once every second or so. My function looks like this

```
$scope.saveProg = function() {
    ProgressService.saveProg({
      topic: $scope.topic,
      message: $scope.message
    })
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "any information to be missing"? when you ng model something on input item, it triggers the digest loop and believe me, it quit fast... when you add ng change, it still an angular stuff, so I guess that the same digest cycle will update what you want. ng change is good to skip your own implementation of scope watchers. I use ng change on inputs, not sure how it works with divs change...

Comment: I've got a form, and upon input change i want some stuff to happen behind the scenes, unrelated to the form. When I debounce the model with ng-options, the model updates after my specified delay, say 2 seconds. I want this delay for the function I'm running with my ng-change, I don't want it to happen where during that 2 second window, the user hits submit and part of their data is missing because of the debounce.

as far as the div, its a directive for a text area with markup essentially but it behaves as an input does as far as everything else is concerned